# loop through words VBA powerpoint

Tags: vba, loops, powerpoint, words

I am new to the powerpoint object model and would like to know why the following snippet of code isn't working. The purpose of the code is to go through a textframe and replace certain words with their lowercase equivalents. I am not sure if I am going about replacing the word correctly...but I am mostly confused about why the program won't "enter" the if statement...even when it finds and "of" and they are both strings!

any help is appreciated! :)

```
Sub findConjectures()

  Dim theWord As TextRange

  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame

   For Each theWord In .TextRange.Words

     MsgBox CStr(theWord) 'just used this as a test

     If CStr(LCase(theWord)) = "of" Then ' this is the part that confuses me!
         theWord.Text = LCase(theWord) 'not sure if this is used correctly
     End If

   Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use the strcomp function, something like.

```
Dim str1 as String = "of"
strcomp(CStr(LCase(theWord)), str1)
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> why the following snippet of code isn't working.

The snippet of code *is* working, it's just not doing what you expect :)

...because each `theWord` may contain trailing spaces: `"of "` <> `"of"`

To handle this potentiality, also the `Trim` function (and you can omit `Cstr` because that is not having any effect here):

```
 If LCase(Trim(theWord)) = "of" Then 
     theWord.Text = LCase(theWord) 
 End If
```

So, we compare the *trimmed* string, but then we replace the entire string, which preserves the trailing space(s).

You may also be interested in the `TextRange.Replace` method, as Steve Rindsberg mentions in the comments.

Comment: Note also that you don't need Cstr at all. It's just converting strings to strings.  No need. You might also want to look at the .TextRange.Replace method, which will preserve any formatting on the replaced text.